# how to deactivate an element from a SVG Element just like it doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have a `SVG` Map with lots of layers (Places) and also text on it.
I wannt to add `hover` effect to the places, but whenever the `curser` goes on the text (which is above the places), the `hover` effect disapears.
is there a way to deactivate the text element(which has been changed to curves) just like it dosn't exest? so the hover effect doesn't disapear?

```css
.circle{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:50px;
  width:100px;
  heigth:100px;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
.background{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.background:hover{
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>

  <div class="circle">001</div>
```

in this example, the `background-element` is my Map and `001 element` is my curved text.

Comment: [`.circle{pointer-events: none}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Whatttt? I taught I've tried it!!! but it worked anyway. TNX.

Answer (score 1):

Your circle needs to be inside your background.

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="circle">001</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Klinkgs: Its a big file with lots of elements, its not possible to change the element's order :/